# What is known about the feminine natural gender for trees in classical Latin?

Tags: noun, gender, mythology, religio

It is a well known fact of Latin grammar, that trees follow *natural gender* and are always feminine, even when the word form would suggest masculine gender, as in *populus* "poplar".

What does motivate this kind of gender assignment? Is there an accepted explanation of that fact?

EDIT: fdb brought up [this forum thread](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/gendering-trees.3361383/) and the main information is that the gender assignment of trees was instable in the development of modern Romance languages, with Portuguese and Sardinian being the most conservative ones in this respect. There is a hint, that the predominance of the feminine gender might be inherited from Proto-Indogermanic.

Comment: *Rōbur, robōris* neuter, is not an exception since it means oak timber (Trojan horse *Robur cavum*  )  *Quercus* fem. oak.

Comment: "Natural gender" is totally the wrong word in this context.

Comment: @fdb Why? My Latin teacher told us in school with this term ("natürliches Geschlecht" in German). Ok, school and research are different spheres, but does it make this terminology wrong?

Comment: Trees are not "naturally" female.

Comment: While the terminology and the naturalness of femininity of trees are debatable, let us keep the focus on the actual question: Why are trees feminine? A discussion of the terminology would make a nice addition to any answer, but it is beside the main point. A separate question about the terminology is a good option.

Comment: @fdb ... for a native speaker of English heavily influenced by either a monotheistic religion or the scientific point of view. Heathen Romans probably had different thoughts about this, and this is the main point of my question.

Comment: perhaps of interest: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/gendering-trees.3361383/

Comment: @fdb Agree! For instance, in present-day Russian, **words** for  trees can be either feminine (береза, сосна) or masculine (дуб, клён).

Comment: I'd like to know this as well. I've looked up a few tree names in De Vaan, but nowhere does he explain why they're feminine. About *quercus* (*u* stem), he says *"...since masculine and feminine **u** and **o** stems tend to influence each other in nominative and accusative singular, and since **o**-stem tree names tend to be feminine, it cannot be excluded that **quercus** continues a Proto-Italic **o** stem."* This suggests that trees with (originally) *u* stems shouldn't be feminine. I don't know enough about the distinction between old *o* and *u* stems, though (which is now invisible?).

Comment: But see [_acer, aceris_ **n.** "maple tree"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/acer#Etymology_2).