# why all tree names in Latin are femininum?

Tags: noun, gender, nature

Why most of the tree names in Latin are femininum? Is there any historical/etymological reason for it?

- quercus [quercūs, f.]
- betula [betulæ, f.]
- alnus [alni, f.]
- fraxinus [fraxini, f.]
- populus [populi, f.]
- cedrus [cedri, f.]
- castanea [castaneæ, f.]
- ulmus [ulmi, f.]
- abiēs [abietis, f.]
- corylus [coryli, f.]
- aquifolium [aquifolii, n.]
- carpinus [carpini, f.]
- larix [laricis, f.]
- salix [salicis, f.]

only exceptions I found:

- sambucus [sambuci, m.]
- acer [aceris, n.]

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take a look at these two questions and comments under them: [one](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/10939/79) and [two](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/16793/79). Unfortunately neither has received an answer.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that it is more interesting than I originally thought.

Comment: Hi Petr. We'll close this for now since it's a duplicate of the other two. Not sure which of the other two are the best to keep open. It is an interesting question (which I suppose is why it keeps getting asked!), so I hope someone attempts at least a partial answer soon. Let me know if you have any questions about this process.

Comment: I'll just add that the exceptions are false positives: *sambūcus* the m. means "sambuca player", and *acer* is almost certainly a lexicographical error due to misinterpretation - the neuter usage in Ovid refers to maple wood the material; in Pliny the neuter adjectives modify *genus* "kind, type" and not the tree-name.

Comment: thanks for the explanation.